# Crop and rearrange duplex scanned A3 pdf into A4 format

Tags: pdf, batch, scanning

I scanned some duplex printed A3 pages stapled in the middle into a multi-page pdf file.

The result kind of looks like this:

```
(left side of the A3 page | right side)
page n   | page 1
page 2   | page n-1
page n-2 | page 3
...
```

Is there any way to batch convert this into an A4 formatted pdf with all the pages in the right order?

Comment: By batching you mean from the command line?

Comment: I don't care if it's from the command line or by using a GUI, just that it can be used without cropping each page manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/pomeloy/a3duplex-to-a4

Not the prettiest but it works.

This python script accepts multiple PDFs as command-line arguments and saves the results in the same directory. For requirements see the github readme.

Comment: I do realise its a program you wrote yourself - but an example of how you'd use it would likely round out the answer better.

Comment: Got it. Better now?